# X3Dom: How many polygons are supported?

Tags: 3d, polygon, blender, x3dom

How many plogyns are supported or do also work high resolution models with many polygons as fast as small models?
Are just polygons supported or also normals and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems also the developers dont even know, relies on the browser and machine where the 3d object is displayed. Have to test this. Seems like high resolution models also work very well.